# cloudinary image doesn't show up

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cloudinary

i'm using next js and cloudinary 
so I uploaded the image to the cloudinary and put the url in the react
The url is https://res.cloudinary.com/doqurzmbt/image/upload/v1594709094/google-analytics-ux_g6w5ti.jpg

but the image did not show up  in react this is my  codesandbox 
https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-christian-y64eb?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

so I tried I just wrote a general image tag and a cloud-react npm but also did not work 
but the other link works very well what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code it's working on my end. here is a screenshot: https://res.cloudinary.com/shirly/image/upload/v1594753839/Screen%20Shot%202020-07-14%20at%2012.10.17%20PM_ulddld.png

Our best practice will be to use something like:

```
<Image cloudName="doqurzmbt" publicId="google-analytics-ux_g6w5ti" width="300" crop="scale" />
```

Same as your code in the example.js code.

Comment: um it's not browser problem.... the problem is adblock (chrome extension) i Turned off the adblock and it worked which is very weird anyway, thanks for your help!