# Next.js Image component doesn't show Cloudinary image

Tags: next.js, cloudinary, nextjs-image

In a previous question, the author tries to load standard DOM `img`:
[cloudinary image doesn't show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62891793/cloudinary-image-doesnt-show-up)

The answer was to specify `cloudName` and `publicId` props to `Image` -

```
<Image cloudName="doqurzmbt" publicId="public id from cloudinary" ... >
```

I'm trying to use the Next `Image` component to work with the Cloudinary image:

1. Fill `next.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  images: {
    deviceSizes: [300, 640, 750, 828, 1080, 1200, 1920, 2048, 3840],
    imageSizes: [16, 32, 48, 64, 96, 128, 256, 384],
    domains: ["res.cloudinary.com"],
    loader: "cloudinary",
  },
};
```

2. Write a sample code:

```
import Image from "next/image";
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <>
      <p>Simple cloudinary example</p>
      <p>Standart image</p>
      <img
        src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dljazkzna/image/upload/v1604677935/img/1053.jpg"
        alt=""
        width="200"
      />
      <p>NextJS Image component</p>
      <Image
        alt="Cloudinary image"
        cloudName="dljazkzna"
        publicId="img/1053"
        width={300}
        height={300}
        src="1053.jpg"
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Codesandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-cloudinary-779pr?file=/pages/index.js

Problems:
`Image` component doesn't show the image.
According to the documentation:
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image
`cloudName` and `publicId` props are absent in the `Image` component.

What are the parameters I need to pass to the Next `Image` component?

Cloudinary image has these properties:

```
src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dljazkzna/image/upload/v1604677935/img/1053.jpg"
cloudName="dljazkzna"
publicId="img/1053"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer at this place:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/18538

Problem was in next.config.js
The working variant is :

```js
module.exports = {
      images: {
        domains: ["res.cloudinary.com"],
      },
    };
```

uinstinct wrote that don't possible mix domains parameter and loader parameter.
In case of `domain = ["res.cloudinary.com"]` src accepts absolute URL.